# Why do I get SSL error when connecting to local domain in MAMP PRO?

Tags: ssl, mamp-pro

I'm using MAMP PRO version 4.1.1 on Mac Sierra.

I have created a domain name and a self signed certificate.

When I right click the host name and choose **Open Host in Web Browser**, the site loads improperly, as many page assets throw the error:

```
Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.
```

I'm sure there is something obvous that I am missing, but I dont know what.

Comment: Did that start with Chrome 58?